# Problbem with map function

Tags: tcl

I'm beginner with TCL and I try to refactor my code with variables inside a map function.

The source code without refactoring :

```
set data " version=\"1.03a\" ddgsdgfs"    
set data [string map {version=\"1.03a\" version=\"2.1\"} $data]
```

No problem, map works

```
set arg_current_version "1.03a"
set arg_target_version "2.1"
set data " version=\"1.03a\" ddgsdgfs"

set version_current "version=\"$arg_current_version\""
set version_target "version=\"$arg_target_version\""
set data [string map {$version_current $version_target} $data]
```

Not working ..... any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set data [string map {$version_current $version_target} $data]
```

In Tcl `{braces}` are like the shell's single quotes -- they are a quoting mechanism that **prevents variable substitution**

You'll want to use the `list` command there:

```
set data [string map [list $version_current $version_target] $data]
```

See [the 12 rules of Tcl syntax](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), number 6